# Copiando array de caracteres usando memcpy

Tags: c

Buenas, Alguien me sabría decir la diferencia entre

```
static unsigned char cmd_code[2];
memcpy(&cmd_code, command+offset, 2);
```

y

```
static unsigned char cmd_code[2];
memcpy(cmd_code, command+offset, 2);
```

En los dos casos el compilador no me da ningún error, sin embargo no consigo copiar los caracteres deseados a cmd_code. Cuál sería en este caso la forma correcta de copiar X caracteres de un array de caracteres a otro?

Comment: Que tipo de dato es `command`?

Comment: command es de tipo unsigned char *

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static unsigned char cmd_code[2];
memcpy(&cmd_code, command+offset, 2);
```

`cmd_code` es un puntero de tipo `char` (`char*`). Por tanto, al hacer `&cmd_code` estás obteniendo un puntero doble (`char**`)

`memcpy` espera recibir un puntero simple, luego el primer diseño está mal y es peligroso.

```
static unsigned char cmd_code[2];
memcpy(cmd_code, command+offset, 2);
```

En este caso voy a asumir, porque no lo indicas en ninguna parte, que `command` es un puntero (me da igual que sea de tipo `char`, `void`, etc.).

En este caso estás copiando en `cmd_code` 2 bytes empezando a contar en la posición `offset` del puntero `command`.

Por ilustrar un ejemplo, si `offset` valiese 10 el equivalente en instrucciones simples sería:

```
cmd_code[0] = command[10];
cmd_code[1] = command[11];
```

Si en este segundo caso no te copia lo que deseas tal vez esté mal configurada la llamada a la función, pero sin más detalles es imposible saber dónde está el error.

---

Edito para indicar por qué es peligroso el primer ejemplo.

```
char c[16];
char* ptr = c;
```

Imaginemos que `c` se encuentra en la posición de memoria `0x1000`. Entonces `ptr` se encontrará en `0x1010`.

Si hacemos:

```
memcpy(ptr,"hola",4);
```

Estaremos escribiendo en `0x1000`, que es la dirección apuntada por `ptr`, es decir, estamos escribiendo en nuestro buffer `c`.

Si ahora cambiamos la línea y hacemos:

```
memcpy(&ptr,"hola",4);
```

Ahora vamos a escribir en 0x1010, ya que es lo que le estamos pasando a la función es la dirección de memoria donde se encuentra `ptr`. En consecuencia escribiremos fuera de `c`, lo que implica que estaremos sobreescribiendo valores que no deseamos.

Un ejemplo:

```
struct test
{
  char test0; // variable de control
  char c[16];
  char test1; // variable de control
  char* ptr;
  char test2; // variable de control
};

int main()
{
  struct test test;

  // Aquí unicamente estoy inicializando la estructura
  memset(&test,0,sizeof(test));
  test.ptr = test.c;

  memcpy(test.ptr,"abcdefghijklmno",16);
  printf("%s - %i - %i - %i\n",test.c,test.test0,test.test1,test.test2);

  memcpy(&test.ptr,"hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh",16);
  printf("%s - %i - %i - %i\n",test.c,test.test0,test.test1,test.test2);
}
```

He declarado las variables en una estructura para garantizar que el compilador las deja correctamente ordenadas.

En mi caso si ejecuto ese código obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
abcdefghijklmno - 0 - 0 - 0
abcdefghijklmno - 0 - 0 - 104
```

Si te fijas, la variable `test2` ha cambiado misteriosamente de valor, mientras que el contenido de `c` permanece inalterable en el segundo caso. Ahí se demuestra que estás pisando variables.

Comment: Consulta ¿Porque dices que es peligroso?

Comment: @Monpeco Revisa mi respuesta que la acabo de editar para responderte.

Comment: excelente exposición, pero no estoy seguro que eso aplica para  `memcpy(&cmd_code` y `memcpy(cmd_code`, porque ambos apuntan a la misma dirección

Comment: @Monpeco. Que en un caso particular no falle no quiere decir que te vaya a funcionar siempre. Yo no iría mezclando alegremente punteros de diferentes tipos porque el resultado de ese cóctel no te va a gustar

Comment: @Monpeco También recordarte que te he comentado que con lo escueta de tu pregunta es imposible darte una respuesta mejor

Comment: Entiendo @eferion, lastima que el autor de la pregunta no está por aquí para que participe de la discusión. De nuevo, excelente exposición.

Comment: @Monpeco lo siento, te confundí :)

Comment: siento no haber podido ver la discusión antes. Todo parece claro, muchas gracias por la respuesta. En cualquier caso, para dar más info, decir que command es unsigned char * como preguntaba un miembro